# DNS problems when connecting via VPN

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn

So on my home network I run my own domain controller & DNS server. On my client machine (which is a member of this home domain), I connect to my work VPN and from that point my DNS messes up.

My internet works because I unchecked "Use default gateway on remote network", so that's not a problem. I also have explicitly set the primary DNS suffix of my NIC (Local Area Connection 2) to dailey.home.com, since that is the domain of my internal network. Ideally I don't want to manually set it, but I did it anyway because I thought it might help.

Before I connect to my VPN, my ipconfig /all for "Windows IP Configuration" looks like this:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bob
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : dailey.home.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : dailey.home.com
```

When I connect to my VPN, then it changes to this:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bob
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : dailey.home.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : dailey.home.com
                                       pacs.local
```

My router, which is my default gateway on my home network, has the domain name "router", which points to 10.3.1.1. When I type "router" into my browser (BEFORE connecting to my VPN), I correctly reach my router's HTTP firmware page.

After I connect to the VPN, I do NOT reach the firmware page. When I run a PING on "router", it no longer says 10.3.1.1, but instead has an IP address of 66.114.124.140, which I don't recognize.

In fact, when I try to use ANY local DNS name I have setup, such as computer names or the name of my printer, NONE of them work while the VPN is connected. The IP address is the same for all of them: 66.114.124.140. In fact, if I try a domain name that doesn't even exist, I still get a response from the same IP address.

While connected to the VPN, nslookup for my 'router' returns this (even for a fake domain name!):

```
C:\Users\robert>nslookup router
Server:  svitdc03.pacs.local
Address:  172.16.0.56

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    router.dailey.home.com
Address:  66.114.124.140
```

With the VPN disconnected, nslookup for 'router' returns the expected results:

```
C:\Users\robert>nslookup router
Server:  server.dailey.home.com
Address:  10.3.1.120

Name:    router.dailey.home.com
Address:  10.3.1.1
```

Why is this happening? I don't quite understand. Below is the rest of my IPCONFIG results, with the VPN included.

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Bob
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : dailey.home.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : dailey.home.com
                                       pacs.local

PPP adapter True Automation:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : pacs.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : True Automation
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.196(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.56
                                       172.16.0.42
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dailey.home.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-BC-01-55-34
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.31(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.128
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, May 01, 2011 11:25:58 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Monday, May 02, 2011 11:25:59 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.120
                                       208.67.222.222
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1F-BC-01-55-35
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.dailey.home.com:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : dailey.home.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5efe:10.3.1.31%12(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.3.1.120
                                       208.67.222.222
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{4827DF55-4B5E-405B-BE43-9B40BB4D7804}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.pacs.local:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : pacs.local
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Comment: Quick and dirty fix for you would be to add entries in your HOSTS file for the devices on your home network you want to connect to.  Then when your VPN is connected, it won't matter what DNS is doing...

Comment: @charnley Thanks for the tip but I simply just want to fix the issue properly. This also applies to intranet names across my VPN, I cannot access them either. In some cases if I apply the VPN network's DNS suffix explicitly it will work, but not always.

Comment: Is the VPN setup for split tunneling?

Comment: @Joseph I'm not sure, I'm pretty new with VPNs. I'm using Windows 7 and setting up the VPN connection through windows. How can I check?

Comment: You will have to ask your work network administrator. Depending on how the VPN is setup, it could be causing you to lose local LAN if the security settings are setup that way.

Comment: So I did some digging and the problem seems to be unrelated to the VPN, but instead related to my domain name of choice for my network. My domain name is "dailey.home.com". The IP address of "home.com" through regular DNS servers (like Google or OpenDNS) is 66.114.124.140. I think that when I do a domain that doesn't exist, it tries to resolve it as foo.dailey.home.com and then tries foo.home.com, where it returns the IP address of 66.114.124.140. I may try renaming my domain to see if that helps.

Comment: I was thinking you might be in trouble with that AD name.  Pick something like home.local.  Unfortunately it is not going to be fun renaming your domain.  Good luck with your schema editing!

Comment: @charnley I did the RENDOM stuff, but didn't add my DNS zone first so now I've got to muck around with that. Once I add & setup my new DNS zone I should be ready to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your VPN is disconnected, your client's resolver uses your home DNS server to resolve names. When you try to access the hostname `router`, it uses the search path and asks your server for the address of `router.dailey.home.com`, and all is well.

When your VPN is connected, your VPN client and network settings point your client's resolver to your work DNS server. When you try to access the hostname `router`, your computer asks your work DNS server for the address of `router.dailey.home.com`. Since, as you've noted, the authoritative servers for the `home.com` domain return a valid answer for that domain name, the resolver stops there. If, instead, you changed your domain name to something not resolvable by Internet DNS servers, such as `home.local`, your work DNS server would still have no way of resolving `router.home.local` to an IP address, and would likely return an authoritative NXDOMAIN answer, i.e. "this domain does not exist." This configuration would fix your inability to reach intranet hosts without fully qualified names, since your client would proceed to the next element of your search path, but you still wouldn't be able to reach your home machines.

The best solution I can think of is to set up your client to prefer your Local Area Connection 2 (Control Panel > Network and Internet (View network status and tasks)> Change adapter settings; press Alt and choose Advanced Settings; and then modify the adapter order), and then to configure your DNS server to delegate responsibility for the `pacs.local` domain to your work DNS server. This arrangement still has the problem that you won't be able to get to any Internet-facing machines in `pacs.local` when your VPN is not connected, but given that the TLD is `.local`, I expect that won't be a problem. You may possibly still run afoul of requirements from your VPN client.